# How do I derive Pauli's exclusion principle with path integrals?

Tags: path-integral, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, anyons

I am trying to prove Pauli's exclusion principle using path integrals. My starting point is the configuration space $\mathcal{C}$ for two indistinguishable particles in 3D:

$$ \mathcal{C} = \{ \{x_1,x_2\}:x_i \in \mathbb{R}^3,x_1 \neq x_2 \} $$

The fundamental group $\pi_1 (\mathcal{C})$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes of paths $\gamma :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{C} $ where two paths are equivalent if they are homotopic. I can deduce that for my configuration space

$$ \pi_1(\mathcal{C}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 $$

which correspond to the two classes of paths where the particles exchange positions and those that don't. Now I have been told that this implies the existence of two species of particles, namely fermions and bosons. I am unsure why but I continue anyway. The propagator is defined as

$$ \langle \mathbf{x}_f,t_f|\mathbf{x}_i,t_i \rangle = \sum_{\alpha \in \pi_1(\mathcal{C})}\rho(\alpha) K(\alpha)$$

where $\mathbf{x}_{i,f}$ are the initial and final configurations in $ \mathcal{C}$, $\rho(\alpha)$ is a representation of the homotopy class $\alpha \in \pi_1(\mathcal{C})$ and $K(\alpha)$ is the usual Feynman path integral over all paths within the $\alpha$ homotopy class. I take my initial and final configurations as $ \mathbf{x}_{i,f}= \{ x_1,x_2 \}$, and choose the paths $\alpha $ such that they interchange the particles with a representation $\rho(\alpha) = -1$, therefore the propagator above becomes

$$ \langle \mathbf{x}_f,t_f|\mathbf{x}_i,t_i \rangle = - K(\alpha)$$

I am unsure what this is telling me. There is a minus sign but is this equivalent to the usual result in terms of state vectors

$$ |\psi(x_1,x_2) \rangle = - |\psi(x_2,x_1 )\rangle?$$

How would I go from the propagator to Pauli's exlusion principle? I explicity stated that my configuration space does not include instances where $x_1 = x_2$, so I cannot use this to see what happens when both particles are at the same position. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: write the amplitude of $\langle x_1,x_2|U|x_1,x_2 \rangle$ as a path integral in first quantized picture. Then if you choose a specific path  for exmaple one particle   encircles the other, you will find that therw ill be a phase. With this method you can calculate the corresponding phase of exchange and braiding. I am not sure if you can proove pep.

Comment: Notice that the classical configuration space you wrote is simply connected. What you want to consider is $\mathcal C / S_2$, where $S_2$ acts on $\mathcal C$ as $(x_1,x_2)\to (x_2,x_1)$.

Comment: @pppqqq I explicitly defined $ \mathcal{C} $ in terms of sets and not ordered pairs, so what I have written is not simply connected

Comment: Oh. Anyway, you may try to have look at these notes http://www.sissa.it/tpp/phdsection/download.php?ID=3349&filename=Instantons.pdf